# How to Select Between Two Specific Date Ranges

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, between

Say I want a specific interval like (mm/dd/yyyy-1 - 1/1/yyyy-1)

How could I query this in postgres?

So far I've worked out something along the lines of:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE date BETWEEN (now()::DATE - INTERVAL '1 year') - ‘1/1/?’ AND (now() - INTERVAL '1 year') - ‘1/1/?’
```

I'm not quite sure how to get the previous year.

Am I on the right track? Sorry, I'm new to this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `date_trunc()` to get the beginning of the year:

```
select *
from my_table
where date >= date_trunc('year', current_date - interval '1 year')
  and date  < date_trunc('year', current_date)
```

`date_trunc('year', current_date)` returns the first day of *this* year. As I have used `<` as the upper bound, this will include all dates until the December, 31st in the previous year.

If you do want to use `BETWEEN` (which will only work properly if `date` is defined with the data type `date`) then you can use:

```
select *
from my_table
where date between date_trunc('year', current_date - interval '1 year')::date
               and date_trunc('year', current_date)::date - 1
```

Note that the upper limit was cast to a `date` and then I subtracted 1 day to land on December 31. This is necessary because `between` *includes* both values.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! However is there a way to rephrase the query to use BETWEEN... AND..? And is there a reason to use date_trunc over say "now()::DATE - INTERVAL '1 year'" to get mm/dd/yyyy-1 ?

Comment: If you are dealing with timestamps it's basically always better to use `>= ... AND <` rather than `BETWEEN`. But if you really want to use between, see my edit

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can use something like this:

```
select * from table 
 where data between to_date(concat('01/01/', EXTRACT (YEAR FROM now()) - 1), 'mm/dd/yyyy') and (now()::DATE - interval '1 year')
```

But the more used is `date_trunc`:

```
select * from table
where date >= date_trunc('year', now()::DATE - interval '1 year')
  and date  < date_trunc('year', now()::DATE)
```

When you use `date_trunc('year', now()::DATE)` the day will be 01, month 01, and year will be the this year.